# Forming the sublist using same indices

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi I am trying to solve a problem where I have to return the indices in a sublist of the same person. When i say same person , I mean if they have the same username,phone or email(any one of them).

I understand that these identites are mostly unique but for the sake of questions lets assume.

eg.

```
data = [("username1","phone_number1", "email1"), 
        ("usernameX","phone_number1", "emailX"), 
        ("usernameZ","phone_numberZ", "email1Z"), 
        ("usernameY","phone_numberY", "emailX"), 
        ("username2","phone_number2", "emailX")]
```

Expected output :

```
[[0,1,3,4][2]]
```

Explaination: As 0,1 have the same phone and 3 and 4 have the same email so They all fall under one category. and 2 index falls in the other catoegry.

My approach until now is :

```
data = [("username1","phone_number1", "email1"), 
              ("usernameX","phone_number1", "emailX"), 
              ("usernameZ","phone_numberZ", "email1Z"), 
              ("usernameY","phone_numberY", "emailX"),
               ] 
               
def match(t1,t2):
    if(t1[0] == t2[0] or t1[1] == t2[1] or t1[2] == t2[2]):
        return True
    else:
        return False
    
# print(match(data[1],data[3]))
together = []
for i in range(len(data)):
    temp = {i}
    for j  in range(len(data)):
        if(match(data[i],data[j])):
            temp.add(j)
    together.append(temp)

for i in range(len(data)):
    ans = together[i]
    for j in range(i+1,len(data)):
        if(bool(ans.intersection(together[j]))):
            ans = ans.union(together[j])
    print(ans)
```

I am not able to reach desired result.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A first solution is similar to yours with some enhancements:

- Leveraging `any` for the match, such that it doesn't require to know the number of items inside the tuples.
- Checking if a user is already identified as part of "together" to skip useless comparison

Here it is:

```
together = set()
for user_idx, user in enumerate(data):

    if user_idx in together:
        continue  # That user is already matched

    # No need to check with previous users
    for other_idx, other in enumerate(data[user_idx + 1 :], user_idx + 1):
        # Match
        if any(val_ref == val_other for val_ref, val_other in zip(user, other)):
            together.update((user_idx, other_idx))

isolated = set(range(len(data))) ^ together
```

Another solution use tricks by going through a numpy array to identify isolated users. With numpy it is easy to compare a user to every other user (aka the original array). An isolated user will only match one time to itself on each of its fields, hence summing the boolean values along fields will return, for an isolated user, the length of the tuple of fields.

```
data = np.array(data)

# For each user, match it with the whole matrice
matches = sum(user == data for user in data)

# Isolated users only match with themselves, hence only have 1 on their line
isolated = set(np.where(np.sum(matches, axis=1) == data.shape[1])[0])

# Together are other users
together = set(range(len(data))) ^ set(isolated)
```

see the `matches` array for better understanding:

```
[[1 2 1]
 [1 2 3]
 [1 1 1]
 [1 1 3]
 [1 1 3]]
```

However, it is not leveraging any of the optimisation mentioned before.
Still, numpy is fast so it should be ok.